Serialize enum to JSON using the value of the EnumMember attribute in ASP.NET
I have an enum like this:
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using My.Custom.Namespace.Converters;

[TypeConverter(typeof(CustomEnumConverter<EFoo>))]
[JsonConverter(typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter))]
public enum EFoo
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "VALUE1")]
    Value1Enum = 1,
    
    [EnumMember(Value = "VALUE2")]
    Value2Enum = 2
}

The values of this enum are used in DTOs returned from an AspNetCore MVC controller like this: return this.Ok(someDto).
What I need the serialized JSON to look like:
{
    "foo": "VALUE1",
    ...
}

What it actually looks like:
{
    "foo": "Value1Enum",
    ...
}

Is there a way to force ASP.NET to use the value of the EnumMember attribute when serializing the enum behind the scenes without making a change to the original enum definition?
EDIT:
Added usings to the enum code.
Framework is ASP.NET Core version 6.0.
I searched Startup.cs for anything relevant to json serialization and found this:
services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase));
    });


Are you using ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core?  And which version?  If [JsonConverter(typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter))] is not working, chances are you are using an ASP.NET version that does not use Json.NET as its default serializer.  A [mcve] indicating the .NET + Library versions you are using + your startup configuration code would clarify.

Please also share all of the using Namespace; declarations at the top of the file containing EFoo.  Both Newtonsoft.Json and System.Text.Json have a class named JsonConverterAttribute so you need to be sure you are using the correct one.

ASP.NET Core version 6.0 uses System.Text.Json by default not Json.NET, and System.Text.Json does not support EnumMember or any other attribute for specifying custom enum names.  So you must use your own converter as shown in System.Text.Json: How do I specify a custom name for an enum value? (the accepted answer shows a converter specifically for EnumMember) or revert back to Json.NET as shown in How to use Newtonsoft.Json as default in Asp.net Core Web Api?. Do either of those answer your question also?

@dbc Thank you very much and yes, you did answer my question. In the end, we decided we want to get rid of Json.NET in the future and use System.Text.Json instead, so our solution to the problem is to regenerate the enums in the model with the desired values (my original example would now look like this: public enum EFoo { VALUE1 = 1 }.

@dbc We found that regenerating the model would be a cleaner solution than writing a converter in our case, although generally, I would say it's the most accurate answer to my original question.
